# Using ASP TabPanel Onclick

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi and thanks in advance,

I have 2 tabs. Each already has some asp and html markup. When on the 1st tab, I need to call a c# method. I noticed the attribute OnClientClick is for javascript. So is there a way for me call my c# method when the 1st tab is selected?

```
    <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" CssClass="ajax__tab_ie-theme camera-tab"
                TabIndex="0">
                <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanelVTMCoord" runat="server" HeaderText="UTM" >
                    <ContentTemplate>
.
.
.
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:TabPanel>
                <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPaneLatLong" runat="server" HeaderText="Lat/Long">
                    <ContentTemplate>
.
.
.
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:TabPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the documentation here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/tabs-control.ashx

`asp:TabContainer` has `ActiveTabChanged` that you can use.